# ios Open app with webapp

Tags: ios, xcode, web-applications

I have two question regarding ios app.

If I have a webapp(Open with safari), is it possible to call some function that will open up an app that my code refernce to that the user already download?

For example if I have facebook app downloaded on my iPhone already, and I use the Facebook Login Api in my webapp, is it possible to open up the Facebook app with web app after the user click "login with facebook".

Second question is if I use UIWebView to embed a web app into an ipa app, is it possible to call a function and open up another app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it is possible to do that.

First in appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    BOOL returnValue = NO;
    NSString *urlString = [url absoluteString];
    if([urlString hasPrefix:@"appgo://"]){  
         returnValue = YES;
    }
   return returnValue;
}
```

Then in Info.Plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.xxxx.appgo</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>appgo</string>
            <string>yourSecondScheme</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```